# ggplot function like points

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there any way to add points to a ggplot graph like with the `points()` function in base graphics? I don't often use ggplot and always prefer base graphics, but this time I must to deal with it. With `+ geom_point(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(1,2,3))` there is an error:

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (33049): x, y

Comment: I'd recommend you first take a look at some ggplot tutorials and the docs. The function takes its data via a data frame, not individual vectors

Comment: @camille Thanks! I cannot appreciate your comment as an answer, but definitely I should! This New Year's morning searching for some good reads about ggplot2 advances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're looking for, but you can use the `data=` argument to `geom_point()` to override the default behaviour (which is to inherit data from the original `ggplot` call); as @dc37 points out, `x` and `y` need to be specified within a data frame, but you can do this on the fly. You might also need to specify the mapping, if the original x and y variables aren't called `x` and `y` ...

```
+ geom_point(data= data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(1,2,3)),
             mapping = aes(x=x, y=y))
```

Alternatively (and maybe better):

```
+ annotate( geom="point", x = 1:3, y = 1:3)
```

From `?annotate`:

> This function adds geoms to a plot, but unlike [a typical] geom
>        function, the properties of the geoms are not mapped from
>        variables of a data frame, but are instead passed in as vectors.
>        This is useful for adding small annotations (such as text labels)
>        or if you have your data in vectors, and for some reason don't
>        want to put them in a data frame.

Comment: Your answer is much more elaborated than mine and address I think all possible situations. I will delete mine. (BTW, nice way to use `annotate`, I will keep in mind for my personal record)

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker, yours ```annotate``` answer rocks! I have approx. 40000 entries of 7 variables, and clustered that data.frame with CLARA. Because factoextra ```fviz_cluster``` output looks nicer for presentation than clusplot, I was puzzled when I had to add points just from the first principal component (the function uses PCA for dimensions reduction). With clusplot base ```points``` works well, but factoextra functions uses ggplot2 engine, and obviously I'm not so familiar with ggplot. Thanks again and best wishes for New Year! :-)